# SVG. Анимация при нажатии на машинку

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

[Ссылка на SVG](https://fex.net/ru/s/6bo7zy3).
При нажатии на машинку она должна передвигаться к краю экрана;
При двойном нажатии на машинку она должна возвращаться обратно.
**НО что бы при нажатии на колеса машинки , анимация передвижения НЕ срабатывала !**

```js
function changeRweel() {
    let rweel = document.querySelector("#rweel");
    rweel.style.fill = "#3f3f9f";
}
function changeLweel() {
    let lweel = document.querySelector("#lweel");
    lweel.style.fill = "#3f3f9f";
}

var el = document.getElementById("drop-lang");
document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0].addEventListener('click',
    function() {
    el.classList.toggle("active");
})
```

```css
svg {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    position: relative;
}
svg path {
    fill:inherit;
    stroke:inherit;
    stroke-width:inherit;
    }

#rweel, #lweel {
    fill: #464655;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#rweel:hover, #lweel:hover {
    fill: green;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#drop-lang {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transition: transform 3s;
}

#drop-lang.active {
    transform: translateX(190px);
    transition: transform 3s;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="drop-lang" class="lang" viewBox="0 0 512 200">
  <g style="fill:#C7CFE2">
    <rect width="57" height="18" x="7" y="181" transform="rotate(-129 -2 112)"/>
    <path d="M207 58c-6-1-9-8-6-13l6-11c5-8 14-13 23-13h44c8 0 16 4 21 10l31 42-119-15Z"/>
    <path d="m324 15-2-2h-39l61 69 36-17s-42-39-56-50Z"/>
  </g>
  <path style="fill:#FF6464" d="M415 56h-36c-5 0-11 2-15 4l-12 9-5 2-33-44c-2-2 0-6 3-6h14l-7-6c-7-6-20-12-50-12h-44c-19 0-38 4-55 13l-62 31H35C21 47 9 59 9 74v79l62 18h432v-27c0-49-39-88-88-88Zm-208 2c-6-1-9-8-6-13l6-11c5-8 14-13 23-13h44c8 0 16 4 21 10l31 42-119-15Z"/>
  <path style="fill:#D2555A" d="M503 180H106c-5 0-9-4-9-9s4-9 9-9h397c5 0 9 4 9 9s-4 9-9 9Z"/>
  <circle style="fill:#D7DEED" cx="415" cy="144" r="44"/>
  <path onclick="changeRweel()" id="rweel" d="M415 197c-29 0-53-24-53-53s24-53 53-53 53 24 53 53-24 53-53 53Zm0-88c-20 0-35 16-35 35 0 20 15 36 35 36a35 35 0 0 0 0-71Z"/>
  <circle style="fill:#B8BFD4" cx="415" cy="144" r="18"/>
  <g style="fill:#D2555A">
    <path d="m79 180-2-1-70-17c-5-2-8-6-7-11s6-8 11-6l71 17c4 1 7 6 6 11-1 4-5 7-9 7Z"/>
    <path d="m9 100 12 13c4 3 5 7 5 12v37l-17-9v-53Z"/>
    <path d="M294 144H141c-5 0-9-4-9-9 0-4 4-8 9-8h153c7 0 14-3 19-8l13-14c4-3 9-3 13 0 3 4 3 9 0 13l-13 13c-9 9-20 13-32 13Z"/>
  </g>
  <circle style="fill:#D7DEED" cx="97" cy="144" r="44"/>
  <path onclick="changeLweel()" id="lweel" d="M97 197c-29 0-53-24-53-53s24-53 53-53 53 24 53 53-24 53-53 53Zm0-88a35 35 0 0 0 0 71c20 0 35-16 35-36 0-19-15-35-35-35Z"/>
  <circle style="fill:#B8BFD4" cx="97" cy="144" r="18"/>
  <path style="fill:#FF8B8B" d="m15 57 339 33c5 1 10 0 14-2 20-10 90-34 135 46-5-44-43-78-88-78h-36c-5 0-11 2-15 4l-12 9-5 2s-3 4-21 2l-71-9-142-17H35c-8 0-15 4-20 10Z"/>
  <path style="fill:#FF6464" d="M44 29H22c-8 0-15-4-17-12l-3-7C1 6 3 3 7 3h37c5 0 9 4 9 9v9c0 5-4 8-9 8Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Js  тут лишний, svg  работает с click без js ...

Comment: @MonkeyMutant вынести логику js из svg не самая плохая идея.

Comment: @DiMithras в svg click обрабатывается без javascript вообще

Comment: @MonkeyMutant в [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/onclick) идет js код. Чем городить его внутри атрибута, чем хуже вынести в отдельный блок? Или о чем речь, о CSS без JS, об анимации?

Comment: @DiMithras если хотите - можете проверить таким образом - выключить js в браузере и посмотрите будет ли работать локальный js в подключеном svg и будет ли работать это: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/onclick

Comment: и пишу я о чистом svg - в котором есть такие же методы  как и в javascript

Comment: "*Такие же методы как в javascript*", но "*без js вообще*", это и есть JS, который можно поместить в `<script>`, но зачем это городить, если в вопросах / ответах на SO можно вынести в отдельный блок? Обсуждаемый атрибут один и тот же, он, к слову, есть как в вопросе, так и в ответе, без разницы, непосредственно в SVG он, или в отдельном файле, обрабатываться одинаково будет. Собственно, это одна из причин почему SVG блокируется CORS. На лень можно что угодно списать, но ваш посыл совершенно непонятен.

Comment: @DiMithras я,там не правильно написал, в svg есть свои методы работы с сущностями, begin в котором значение click, mousemove и т д...

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/mdQJeMe  вот без js вообще

Comment: @MonkeyMutant про begin не знал, ранее просто зацикленные анимации делал, спасибо 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С группами вы через чур намудрили.

Во-первых, есть какие-то пустые, зачем? Не надо так делать, оформляйте вопрос красиво. Во-вторых, есть у вас две группы по цветам, например `#C7CFE2`, но вы эти цвета для каждой фигуры пропысываете, хотя можно прописать для группы, это более оптимально и отлично ложится в DRY принципы.

И, группы это ваш ключ для решения проблемы.
Создадим новую группу, в которую будут входить все фигуры кроме колёс, пусть у неё будет **ID** "*chasis*". Правильнее, конечно, английское слово *body*, но мне не нравится, что оно перекликается с синтаксисом html.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0]
```

Это, конечно, изврат. Зачем искать все элементы и брать первый? Ставим вместо этого новый ID группы отвечающий за корпус, теперь `'click'` будет работать только на корпусе, а на колёса реагировать не будет.
<sub>Можно, конечно, обойтись без ID и использовать `onclick` прямо на группе, но тогда придётся ещё [стиль дописать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49739738/8489602), что получится более громоздко.</sub>

```js
function changeTire(clicked_element) {
    clicked_element.style.stroke = "#3f3f9f";
}

document.getElementById("chasis").addEventListener('click',
    function() {
    document.getElementById("drop-lang").classList.toggle("active");
})
```

```css
svg {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    position: relative
}

.rear { cx: 96 }
.front { cx: 415 }

.wheel, .tire {
    stroke-width: 18;
    cy: 144
}

.wheel {
    fill: #b8bfd4;
    stroke: #d7deed;
    r: 27
}

.tire {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #464655;
    r: 44
}

.tire:hover {
    stroke: green;
    cursor: pointer
}

#drop-lang {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transition: transform 3s
}

#drop-lang.active {
    transform: translateX(190px);
    transition: transform 3s
}
```

```html
<svg id="drop-lang" viewBox="0 0 512 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="chasis">
    <g fill="#C7CFE2">
      <rect width="57" height="18" x="7" y="181" transform="rotate(-129 -2 112)"/>
      <path d="M207 58c-6-1-9-8-6-13l6-11c5-8 14-13 23-13h44c8 0 16 4 21 10l31 42-119-15Z"/>
      <path d="m324 15-2-2h-39l61 69 36-17s-42-39-56-50Z"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="#FF6464">
      <path d="M415 56h-36c-5 0-11 2-15 4l-12 9-5 2-33-44c-2-2 0-6 3-6h14l-7-6c-7-6-20-12-50-12h-44c-19 0-38 4-55 13l-62 31H35C21 47 9 59 9 74v79l62 18h432v-27c0-49-39-88-88-88Zm-208 2c-6-1-9-8-6-13l6-11c5-8 14-13 23-13h44c8 0 16 4 21 10l31 42-119-15Z"/>
      <path d="M44 29H22c-8 0-15-4-17-12l-3-7C1 6 3 3 7 3h37c5 0 9 4 9 9v9c0 5-4 8-9 8Z"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="#D2555A">
      <path d="M503 180H106c-5 0-9-4-9-9s4-9 9-9h397c5 0 9 4 9 9s-4 9-9 9Z"/>
      <path d="m79 180-2-1-70-17c-5-2-8-6-7-11s6-8 11-6l71 17c4 1 7 6 6 11-1 4-5 7-9 7Z"/>
      <path d="m9 100 12 13c4 3 5 7 5 12v37l-17-9v-53Z"/>
      <path d="M294 144H141c-5 0-9-4-9-9 0-4 4-8 9-8h153c7 0 14-3 19-8l13-14c4-3 9-3 13 0 3 4 3 9 0 13l-13 13c-9 9-20 13-32 13Z"/>
    </g>
    <path fill="#FF8B8B" d="m15 57 339 33c5 1 10 0 14-2 20-10 90-34 135 46-5-44-43-78-88-78h-36c-5 0-11 2-15 4l-12 9-5 2s-3 4-21 2l-71-9-142-17H35c-8 0-15 4-20 10Z"/>
  </g>
  <circle class="rear wheel"/>
  <circle class="rear tire" onclick="changeTire(this)"/>
  <circle class="front wheel"/>
  <circle class="front tire" onclick="changeTire(this)"/>
</svg>
```

И ещё немного по оптимизации. Внутренняя часть колёс делается одним кругом, если задать `fill` и `stroke`. Для шин `path` не нужен, также можно обойтись кругом и обращаться к stroke.

Вообще колёса можно было бы в `symbols` запихнуть, но количество кода это не сократит, т.к. `path` убран.

Шинам можно задать класс, тогда изначальные цвета и `hover` менять через данный класс не указывая оба колеса.

Под [js](/questions/tagged/js) нет необходимости городить две функции. Если обращаться к `this.id`, то можно получить в функции ID конкретного колеса и изменять его. Но в данном случае и ID не сильно нужен, можно напрямую обращаться к элементу через `this`. В общем, DRY в действии.

Comment: Понял, за срач извиняюсь , только обучаюсь) 
При одном клике на машинку она перемещается в право и в лево, а как сделать что бы в право 1 клик , а в лево 2 клика ?

Comment: Можете ещё помочь реализовать задумку со спойлером на машине пожалуйта, спойлер должен постоянно двигаться вперед-назад на сером креплении и менять цвет с красного на оранжевый

Comment: вот такая задумка 
https://fex.net/ru/s/fzmsfep

Comment: Использовать [dblclick в JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event) либо в SVG, использовать [добавление класса](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp) вместо `.toggle()` и [убирать его](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp). Ссылка ваша не ведёт никуда. По поводу задумки, базу вам объяснили, SO не сайт про "*сделай пожалуйста*", пробуйте. Если не будет получаться, задавайте новый вопрос без "срача", данный отвечен чуть больше чем полностью.

Comment: Благодарю, попробую!